# How can we write a polynomial hash function with given prime

Tags: java, hashcode

So for a given prime number 31, how can I write a hash function for a string parameter?

Here is my attempt.

```
    private int hash(String key){
        int c = 31;
        int hash = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ ) {
            int ascii = key.charAt(i);
            hash += c * hash + ascii; 
    }
        return (hash % sizetable);} // sizetable is an integer which is declared outside. You can see it as a table.length().
```

So, since I can not run any other function in my work and I need to be sure about the process here, I need your answers and help! Thank you so much.

Comment: The String class already provides a good hash algorithm.  Please provide more information in your question.

Comment: Can you clarify why are you not satisfied with the current version? What does `sizetable` variable denotes? Is this method a part of a custom collection?

Comment: Teacher just told try it yourself.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I am not sure if I did the correct thing. I am not working on a big data, therefore there might not contain any exceptions such as "tsih" and "this" has the same integer hashcode. So that even if I wrote the wrong code, it still can be feasible but not logical. So I am asking you people that is it acceptable hashcode?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with two different strings having the same hashcode.  It is expected and would be impossible to avoid given a 32 bit integer and an infinite number of strings.

Comment: It was just a simple question that I asked here since I do not have any friends to talk about. I just wanted to be sure about what I know and what I did.

Comment: Imo, your hash method is fine.

Comment: @chadsqlcoder There's no hash-function that will not produce any collisions (same hash for different input). For me, your current implementation looks ok. If you want to make sure that it doesn't create a lot of collisions - write a test: generate a collection (*or array if you are not comfortable with collections*) of unique random string (*or find some kind of vocabulary on the internet for that*), then create a collection of hashes with your function and determine how many of them are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation looks quite similar to what is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) as standard `String.hashCode()` implementation, this even uses also 31 as prime factor, so it should be good enough.

I just would not assign `31` to a variable, but declare a `private static final` field or use it directly as magic number - not OK in general, but might be OK in this case.

Additionally you should add some tests - if you already know about the concept of unit tests - to prove that your method gives different hashes for different strings. And pick the samples clever, so they are different (for the case of the homework ;)

Comment: *...as a magic number - not OK in general, but might be OK in this case.*  Well, it's certainly ok for the String class.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point out that magic numbers in general are a code smell - but no "rules" without exceptions.